# SQL Server query to transform rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the challenge to query a sql server label with the follow context:

[image]

to get a result like this:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to implement the sql query?

I tried to use the sql pivot function without good results.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, edit the question and add your current attempt.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

This is like the most basic pivot example there can be.
Admittedly, pivot syntax is kinda weird.
From the top of my head:

```sql
select id, [Text01], [Text02], [Text03]
from yourtable
pivot (max(value) for Name in ([Text01], [Text02], [Text03])) pv
```